# Can multimeter measure 3200µF if capacitance measuring range:10p...40n/400n/4µ/40µ/200µF?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, multimeter

A multimeter that has this specifications:

> Capacitance measuring range:10p...40n/400n/4µ/40µ/200µF

will not be able to measure a 300µF or 3200µF capacitor?

That's how it sounds, but I want to make sure since a range up to 200µF sounds pretty useless ...

And it's not an extremely cheap multimeter (though not expensive): https://axiomet.eu/gb/en/product/axiomet/digital-multimeter/ax-594/

Comment: To measure such high capacitance, you can use a battery + resistor + voltmeter + **stopwatch**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meter has a maximum full-scale range of 200µF so no, it will not able to measure a larger capacitor value directly.